# Is there a way to skip some routes in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have been using Angular for some time now.
But there is one functionality I still not figured out how to implement.

Suppose You have created an Examination website in Angular.
When user register with the website he/she will have the list of Examination they can take.
On click of any exam they will see 1 question at a time and answer then accordingly.
At the end they get to see a result.

At this point if user uses browser back or goes back then he/she will see the last question and they can update it. Similar way they will be able to update all the answers until they get 100%. Which is wrong.

What i want to achieve is if your clicks browser back from result screen, they must go back all the way to list of examination. This way they won't be changing any answers.

Note: i can use canDeactivate Gaurd to stop them from going changing route. But for browser back Guards is not called and even i dont want it to stuck user in between without choice other than proceeding.

I want of user goes from scrren A to screen B and from screen b to screen c, when user click or trigger back action from screen c it should take him to screen A.

Comment: Use `replaceUrl` in router. In service, where you save result data check if answer for next question exists. If it does, don't allow saving. You can do same when displaying page, disable the form. Create a guard, similar to service, which will check if you have access to the page

Comment: Thank You...
It helps to skip 1 route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing like this

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('question(1-n)', { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
                this.router.navigate(['result'], { replaceUrl: true });
            });
```